# What information can mouse recorders get?

Tags: keyloggers, spyware

In comparison to keyloggers, mouse recorders do not seem to be able to obtain much sensitive information. For example, passwords, credit card numbers, email addresses, names, passport numbers, etc. can be obtained using keyloggers. But what about mouse loggers? What can mouse positions and mouse clicks reveal to a spy?

Comment: Can't think of anything useful at this point when it comes to mouse positions and clicks. The only interesting thing would be the content of the clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one  knows what is on the screen the movements and clicks tell a lot.

In order to protect against keyloggers some banking applications started to use on-screen keyboards to enter sensitive data like PIN or TAN. But then malware  started to track mouse movements and clicks to get back the information of what the user was doing. Banks tried to fight this with randomized layouts of the keyboards which only lead to not only tracking the mouse movements and clicks but also to do regular screenshots so that the clicks and movements could be interpreted.
See also the article [Virtual Keyboard and the Fight Against Keyloggers](https://www.paladion.net/blogs/virtual-keyboard-and-the-fight-against-keyloggers).

Answer (score -1):

[Virtual Keyboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_keyboard) were being used to tackle keyloggers that captured keystrokes.

Now since the letters clicked on the virtual keyboard cannot be logged in basic keyloggers, this led to the design of mouse keyloggers.

The position of the keys in a virtual keyboard can be known by the attacker if he/she has the idea of the layout. Since the mouse logger captures clicks mentioning the position on the screen, this information can be used to guess the letters clicked.

But a lot of conditions should be met for a key to get matched.

- The layout of the virtual keyboard should be known.
- The resolution of the compromised system in which mouse logger is
  running must be known.
- The site that the victim is browsing must be known.

Even then it will be still tough to guess the key clicked. But nothing will stop a blackhat's willpower/dedication if she/he wants to guess the key at any cost.